# the rain,umbrella and the sun rays

Tags: kinematics

when rain falls vertically, a man running on the road keeps his umbrella tilted but a man standing on the road keeps his umbrella vertical to protect himself from rain.

When I studied the topic further, I found that both men (whether running or standing) keep their umbrella vertical to avoid vertical sun rays. Why is it so?

I m stuck here and can't relate these two situations anyway.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "both men (whether running or standing) keep their umbrella vertical to avoid vertical sun rays"  Technically, that isn't so...  Look up stellar aberration, particularly the work of James Bradley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like this question! Here will be my attempt to explain it. 
-First, let's imagine rain fell much more slowly. Say it took a few seconds for rain to get from the top of the persons head down to the ground. Now, if someone was standing still in this rain they would hold the umbrella straight up so that no rain hit them. But imagine they start running very fast through the rain. Say they're running faster than the raindrops are falling. If they had no umbrella then most of the raindrops would hit the front of their body. You can imagine them running through rain drops which are basically suspended in air so many raindrops hit the front of their body. Since the rain coming from above is falling slowly hardly any of it will hit the top of their head (certainly compared to the amount that would hit the front of their body.) So this person running very fast through slow moving rain would want to hold their umbrella almost entirely horizontal to stop them from "running into" any rain drops.

-Now lets speed the rain up so that it is moving VERY fast, much faster than the person can run. Now if the person is running they won't actually get hit by that many raindrops from the front. Imagine a raindrop a step or two in front of the person. In the other scenario with slow rain it would be easy for the person to "run into" that rain drop and get wet. However, in this scenario that rain drop is going to fall and hit the ground before the person can run into it because this rain moves fast. So in this case, with rain falling faster than the person can run, whether the person is standing still or running they will want to hold the umbrella vertically.

Now, sunlight is light and not rain. This means that sunlight comes down from the sky at the speed of light. This is much much faster than a person can run so there is no worry that by running too fast the person is going to "run into the light" and get sun on their face for example. This is like the second scenario. This means it makes sense for the person in sunlight to hold their umbrella vertically whether they are standing or running.

I'll just point out that there's a more mathematical answer where you can consider the problem in the reference frame of the running person and see that the velocity vector of the rain changes directions as the person runs faster. This could also be analyzed using special relativity to see if the angle of the sun rays changes as the person runs. In my answer I'm neglecting all relativistic effects ($v\ll c$). I'll leave the relativistic/vector answer to someone else.